# Java Records - QueryDSL

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

I would like to use Java Records together with mongoDB & querydsl. However, it seems like querydsl APT is causing an issue. When I try to process simple code (one record and one ordinary class):

```
@QueryEntity
public class TestClass implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return false;
    }
}

@QueryEntity
public record TestRecord() implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the result is:

```
/**
 * QTestClass is a Querydsl query type for TestClass
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.DefaultEntitySerializer")
public class QTestClass extends EntityPathBase<TestClass> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1582647675L;

    public static final QTestClass testClass = new QTestClass("testClass");

    public final ComparablePath<java.util.UUID> id = createComparable("id", java.util.UUID.class);

    public final BooleanPath new$ = createBoolean("new");

    public QTestClass(String variable) {
        super(TestClass.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QTestClass(Path<? extends TestClass> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QTestClass(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(TestClass.class, metadata);
    }

}

/**
 * QTestRecord is a Querydsl query type for TestRecord
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.DefaultEntitySerializer")
public class QTestRecord extends EntityPathBase<TestRecord> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1394409244L;

    public static final QTestRecord testRecord = new QTestRecord("testRecord");

    public final org.springframework.data.domain.QPersistable _super = new org.springframework.data.domain.QPersistable(this);

    public final ComparablePath<java.util.UUID> id = createComparable("id", java.util.UUID.class);

    public final BooleanPath new$ = createBoolean("new");

    public QTestRecord(String variable) {
        super(TestRecord.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QTestRecord(Path<TestRecord> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QTestRecord(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(TestRecord.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

But during processing I received: **cannot find symbol** caused by this line:

```
public final org.springframework.data.domain.QPersistable _super = new org.springframework.data.domain.QPersistable(this);
```

in QTestRecord only. Why is there a difference between Record and Class? Thank you very much!!!

PS: querydsl config:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
.
.
.
          <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>
                                com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor
                            </processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Well, obviously because a Record is not a plain Class and APT does not yet support it.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Querydsl APT 5.0.0 supports records. See [#2798 - Java Record support](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/2798)